# How to remove warnings from “keytool” command in bash

Tags: bash, keytool

How can I remove the warning from the output of

```
keytool -v -alias sssa -list -keystore /var/tmp/certs -storepass passwd | grep 'until' | head -1 | grep -v Warning

Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /opt/miep/msaapp/msa_domain/.keystore -destkeystore /opt/miep/msaapp/msa_domain/.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12".

Valid from: Wed Feb 12 19:00:00 EST 2020 until: Sat Feb 13 07:00:00 EST 2021
```

I need only the last line.

Comment: Append `| tail -n 1`?

Answer (score 3):

Warnings and errors are usually printed to STDERR rather than STDOUT, add a STDERR redirect to get rid of them:

keytool -v -alias sssa -list -keystore /var/tmp/certs -storepass passwd 2>/dev/null | ...

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case here - even "regular messages" are printed to stderr.

Comment: Adding example 
```keytool -v -list -storepass changeit -keystore /opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/cacerts 2>/dev/null | grep redis 
Alias name: redis-tls
  DNSName: test-redis-master
  DNSName: test-redis-master.default.svc
  DNSName: test-redis-master.default.svc.cluster.local```